# Is there a way to copy the file path of an asset in Adobe Bridge?

Tags: windows, copy-paste, filenames, adobe-bridge

Is there a way to copy the file path of an asset in Adobe Bridge? I am using Adobe Bridge on Microsoft Windows.

According to [this thread in the Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1545954):

> Click the last item in the path bar or in the blank space to right of last item.  This will change the address path bar content to an editable mode with the full path highlighted  Then you can copy that to clipboard (and past as desired).  Press Esc to return to the usual path display mode.

However, it only allows to grab the folder path, not the file path (i.e., the filename is missing).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Script found on the Adobe community post
[Copy Path Context Menu](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/629331):

```
#target bridge   
   if( BridgeTalk.appName == "bridge" ) {  
bridgePath = new MenuElement("command", "Path to Clipboard", "at the end of Thumbnail");
}
bridgePath.onSelect = function () { 
   pathToClipboard();
   }
function pathToClipboard(){
var sels = app.document.selections;
app.system("echo "+decodeURI(sels[0].spec.fsName) +"|clip");
}
```

How to use:

- Use the menu *Edit > Preferences... > Startup Scripts*
- Click *Reveal My Startup Scripts*
- Explorer will open on a folder
- Create in this folder a text-file named `Path to Clipboard.jsx`
  containing the above script
- Restart Adobe Bridge
- Confirm adding the script to the context menu.

From now on, an item will be added to the right-click context menu
that is named "Path to Clipboard".